# Can I specify another class's instance-method as a variable for my method?

Tags: python, refactoring, instance-methods

I'm still relatively new to python, 1-2 years of solo-learning, and am trying to improve my code structure so I'm refactoring some old programs I wrote.  In one program, I defined a couple of methods for writing files.  The first uses, "write" to dump a huge http-response.  The second uses "writelines" to dump various derived lists, e.g. lists of links, or forms, or other extracted data.

I'd originally factored out the naming of the file:

```
    @property
    def baseFilename(self):
        unacceptable = re.compile(r'\W+')
        fname = re.sub(unacceptable,'-',self.myUrl)
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
        dstring = "%s%s%s%s%s%s" % (t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute, t.second)
        fullname = fname + '_' + dstring + '.html'
        return fullname
```

But I have a large redundant block of code in each write method:

```
    def writeFile(self, someHtml, writeMethod=write, prefix="RESPONSE_"):
        '''The calling functions will supply only the data to be written and 
           static prefixes, e.g. "full_" for the entire http-response.
        '''

       fullpath = self.myDump + prefix + self.baseFilename
       with open(fullpath, 'w') as h:
           h.write(someHtml)
           h.close()
       print "saved %s" % fullpath
       return fullpath

    def writeList(self, someList, prefix="mechList_"):
        '''Like write file but for one of the many lists outputted.  
           How do I refactor this, since redundant?
        '''

        fullpath = self.myDump + prefix + self.baseFilename
        with open(fullpath, 'w') as h:
            h.writelines(someList)
            h.close()
        print "saved %s" % fullpath
        return fullpath
```

I'd like to be able to add a variable to each function that specifies the write method to use, e.g. (writeMethod=writelines).  I considered just passing in a string and using one of the black-magic functions-- exec() I guess-- but that can't possibly be right since no one ever seems to use those functions.  This whole example may be relatively silly, since I could just work around it, but I decided I'd benefit from knowing how to pass these sorts of instance-methods (is that the right term?).  Is this related to binding and unbinding?  All I need for a good answer is the syntax required to pass 'write,' 'writelines' etc.  Could be simple as: writeMethod = insert_your_syntax_here.  Would love additional explanation or guidance though.  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a "large" redundant block of code.  It's pretty small and focused.   I wouldn't mess with this.  It's fine as it is.  No one wins at code golf.

Comment: Also, the `h.close()` call is complete redundant - it's what the context manager does for you, after all.

Comment: You could make a function for the `fullpath` calculation, would save you "lots" of changing later perhaps. Otherwise I think it looks okay.

Comment: @Skurmedel: Good point about the fullpath calculation.  Appreciate the tip.

Comment: @delnan: I knew context managers acted as failsafes but had somehow gotten the impression I should call close anyway.  Thanks for pointer.

Comment: @S.Lott: Appreciate the encouragement and the advice re: code golf. Looks like you're generally right-- there's no simple way to refactor out the redundant part.  The answers below, though maybe too complex for the situation, are useful for me for study purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a "bound method" from an object, which is then callable as a function without having a reference to the object.

```
f = obj.method
f(args)
# is equivalent to
obj.method(args)
```

However, that's not useful for you, as you create the object you want to use only in the method - you can't pass it in there as bound method. You can factor out the creation of `fullpath`, although this only saves you half of the redundancy. One option, which I'd consider overkill, would be passing a callback which return the function to use for writing.

Another option would be a decorator to factor out all the common parts and push the rest into a callback, the decorated function:

```
def uses_file(prefix_default):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def decorated(self, data, prefix=prefix_default):
            fullpath = obj.myDump + prefix + obj.baseFilename
            with open(fullpath, 'w') as h:
                f(h, data, prefix)
            print "saved", % fullpath
            return fullpath
        return decorated
    return decorator
```

# ...

```
@uses_file(default_prefix="RESPONE_")
def writeFile(self, someHtml, prefix):
   '''...'''
   h.write(someHtml)

@uses_file(default_prefix="mechList_")
def writeList(self, someList, prefix):
    '''...'''
    h.writelines(someList)
```

Comment: Though I'm worried about the complexity of this approach, for anyone trying to understand what I'm doing, I appreciate the elegance, and I can easily imagine situations where the complexity would be merited.  Really appreciate your taking the time to give such a detailed response.  This will certainly go in my decorator library.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this, for instance using lambdas:

```
def writeFile(self, someHtml, writeMethod=lambda f, data: f.write(data), 
              prefix="RESPONSE_"):
    '''The calling functions will supply only the data to be written and 
       static prefixes, e.g. "full_" for the entire http-response.
    '''

   fullpath = self.myDump + prefix + self.baseFilename
   with open(fullpath, 'w') as h:
       writeMethod(h, someHtml)
       h.close()
   print "saved %s" % fullpath
   return fullpath
```